# Can't be blank - Password - Loopback 4 - JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, passwords, loopback

When I want to signup on the loopback API Explorer with a JWT authentication and this json format:

```
{
"id": "string",
"nom": "string",
"prenom": "string",
"email": "string",
"sexe": true,
"dateNaissance": "string",
"password": "strifsvng"
}
```

I had that error message :

```
{
  "error": {
"statusCode": 422,
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "L'instance `User` n'est pas valide. Détails : `password` can't be blank (value: undefined).",
"details": {
  "context": "User",
  "codes": {
    "password": [
      "presence"
    ]
  },
  "messages": {
    "password": [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
  }
 }
 }
 }
```

Here the link of the [documentation's loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html) I've used.

You can see here the user modal :

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class User extends Entity {
   @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: number;

  @property({
     type: 'string',
     required: true,
   })
  nom: string;

  @property({
     type: 'string',
     required: true,
  })
   prenom: string;

   @property({
     type: 'string',
     required: true,
   })
   dateNaissance: string;

  @property({
     type: 'string',
     required: true,
   })
   sexe: string;

  @property({
     type: 'string',
      required: true,
    })
    email: string;

   @property({
     type: 'string',
     required: true,
    })
    password: string;


   constructor(data?: Partial<User>) {
     super(data);
   }
  }

  export interface UserRelations {
    // describe navigational properties here
  }

  export type UserWithRelations = User & UserRelations;
```

and the user controller :

```
// import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {
  Credentials,
  MyUserService,
  TokenServiceBindings,
  User,
  UserRepository,
  UserServiceBindings,
} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';
import {authenticate, TokenService} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {model, property, repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {get, getModelSchemaRef, post, requestBody} from '@loopback/rest';
import {SecurityBindings, securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
import {genSalt, hash} from 'bcryptjs';
import _ from 'lodash';

@model()
export class NewUserRequest extends User {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  password: string;
}

const CredentialsSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  required: ['email', 'password'],
  properties: {
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'email',
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 8,
    },
  },
};

export const CredentialsRequestBody = {
  description: 'The input of login function',
  required: true,
  content: {
    'application/json': {schema: CredentialsSchema},
  },
};

export class UserController {
  constructor(
    @inject(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SERVICE)
    public jwtService: TokenService,
    @inject(UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE)
    public userService: MyUserService,
    @inject(SecurityBindings.USER, {optional: true})
    public user: UserProfile,
    @repository(UserRepository) protected userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

  @post('/users/login', {
      responses: {
        '200': {
          description: 'Token',
          content: {
            'application/json': {
              schema: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                  token: {
                    type: 'string',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })
    async login(
      @requestBody(CredentialsRequestBody) credentials: Credentials,
    ): Promise<{token: string}> {
      // ensure the user exists, and the password is correct
      const user = await this.userService.verifyCredentials(credentials);
      // convert a User object into a UserProfile object (reduced set of properties)
      const userProfile = this.userService.convertToUserProfile(user);

      // create a JSON Web Token based on the user profile
      const token = await this.jwtService.generateToken(userProfile);
      return {token};
    }

    @authenticate('jwt')
    @get('/whoAmI', {
      responses: {
        '200': {
          description: '',
          schema: {
            type: 'string',
          },
        },
      },
    })
    async whoAmI(
      @inject(SecurityBindings.USER)
      currentUserProfile: UserProfile,
    ): Promise<string> {
      return currentUserProfile[securityId];
    }

    @post('/signup', {
      responses: {
        '200': {
          description: 'User',
          content: {
            'application/json': {
              schema: {
                'x-ts-type': User,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })
    async signUp(
      @requestBody({
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: getModelSchemaRef(NewUserRequest, {
              title: 'NewUser',
            }),
          },
        },
      })
      newUserRequest: NewUserRequest,
    ): Promise<User> {
      const password = await hash(newUserRequest.password, await genSalt());
      const savedUser = await this.userRepository.create(
        _.omit(newUserRequest, 'password'),
      );

      await this.userRepository.userCredentials(savedUser.id).create({password});

      return savedUser;
    }
  }
```

I don't know why there are that error as I write something in the password.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Same error. Following their documentation is driving me nuts. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same to me, any fix?